# Using get() inside addSelect - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got this query which returns "3" for example.

```
return CampaignEventStatusUser::where('event_id', 1)->latest()
    ->get()->unique('user_id')->where('status_id', 1)->count();
```

I want to put it into subQuery addSelect like this

```
return EventGroup::where('id', 1)->with('events', function($q) {
        $q->addSelect(['reg_count' =>
            CampaignEventStatusUser::latest()
            ->whereColumn('event_id', 'events.id')
            ->get()->unique('user_id')->where('status_id', 1)->count()
        ]);
    })->get();
```

but I get this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'events.id' in 'where clause'

Below is an example of my table. I expect a count of 2, which will be id 3 & 6.

```
| id | user_id | status_id | 
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | 1001    | 1         | 
| 2  | 1002    | 3         |
| 3  | 1003    | 1         |
| 4  | 1001    | 2         |
| 5  | 1002    | 2         |
| 6  | 1002    | 1         |
```

I know it's something to do with get(), which I believe I need to use to be able to do unique().
groupBy, and distinct don't produce the same results as unique().

Comment: What you're doing now is executing the query in order to get a value to assign to `'reg_count'` however this query is independent of the main query. I would instead use a `join` or a `whereHas`

Comment: @apokryfos I'd like to have my Events brought back with the column "reg_count" with the count I receive from the CampaignEventStatusUser::model. 
I'm still trying to get to grips with Eloquent so I'm not sure how whereHas fits. 

I'm trying to do it using the relationships I already have between Event and CampaignEventStatusUser if possible.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models might help